# Form cassandra cluster by adding service entry in seedslist

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra

I have deployed cassandra cluster with 3 nodes(1 seed and 2 co-ordinator) in kubernetes namespace x and similarly in another namespace y.I have exposed service outside using external load balancer in both namespaces.Now I am trying add the service running in namespace y in namespace x seedslist to form a cluster.

```
namespace x:
seeds:"cassandraserver-0,10.10.10.1:30006"
Here 10.10.10.1 is Loadbalancer Ip and 30006 is port Y.
```

I am expecting that stretch cluster will formed using these two cluster running in namespace x and y. but it didn't happen.In the logs i can see warning

```
WARN  [main] 2020-06-02 09:34:14,326 SimpleSeedProvider.java:60 - Seed provider couldn't lookup host 10.10.10.1:30006
```

Is it possible to from a cassandra cluster using service, if yes please suggest how to do that !!
Thank you !

Comment: transpassing namespaces is a huge security hole. you probably will have to trick it with headless services.

Comment: "cassandra cluster with 3 nodes(1 seed and 2 co-ordinator)"  FYI- any node can be used as a coordinator node.  That's not something which can be designated by config.

Comment: @Suren , I even tried with headless service , but no luck !!